# Having problems seeing how two events are conditionally independent (Craps dice game)

Tags: probability, independence, dice, conditional-probability

**Background:**

$$\text{Show}: \quad E[R\mid\text{win},S=4] = E[R\mid S=4]$$

- where $R$ is the number of rolls of the dice in a game of craps
- $S$ is the initial sum and for this question let's say it's $4$
- You keep rolling two dice until you get either a sum of $4$ (and win) or a sum of $7$ (and lose)

It is true that $E[R\mid\text{win},S=4] = E[R\mid S=4]$ and the explanation in words from Lord Sheldon Ross is in the screenshot below.

---

I now want to show the same conditional independence but using equations.

$$\text{Show}: \quad E[R\mid\text{win},S=4] = E[R\mid S=4]$$

$$ \sum_r r P(R=r \mid\text{win}, S=4)  = \sum_r r P(R=r \mid S=4)  $$

$$ \sum_r r \frac{P(R=r, \text{win}, S=4)}{P(\text{win},S=4)}  = \sum_r r \frac{P(R=r, S=4)}{P(S=4)}$$

$$ \sum_r r \frac{P(R=r, S=4) P(\text{win})}{P(S=4)P(\text{win})}  = \sum_r r \frac{P(R=r, S=4)}{P(S=4)}$$

**My specific question is about the LHS of the final equality above.** I don't believe the probability of winning a craps game is independent of the initial sum being $4$. That is I don't think you can say $P(\text{win}, S=4) = P(\text{win}) P(S=4)$. For example, if your initial sum is $7$ then your probability of winning is $1$. But I know the LHS equals the RHS through the verbal reasoning in the screenshot below. Therefore, to get the LHS to equal the RHS I'd like to take "win" out using conditional independence, that way it will cancel out and the LHS will equal the RHS. Where am I going wrong here?

---

**Book answer below**

[image]

Comment: Note the proper use of \text{} and \mid, as in my edits to this question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks I'm always trying to up my tex game... if you have any insights into my question I would appreciate it!

Comment: I might have posted an answer if your question were clearer. You wrote $\operatorname E(R\mid \text{win},\,S=4).$ But I thought you had said that if $S=4$ then you win. And the answer in the book doesn't seem to consider $\operatorname E(R\mid \text{win},\,S=4).$ And you say if your initial sum is $7$ then you win, but earlier you said that then you lose. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ah craps has a weird rule set. In craps if the first sum is $7$ you do win. But if the first sum is say $4$, then you keep rolling dice until you get a sum of $4$ again (and win) or a sum of $7$ (and lose). Basically $7$ makes you win if it's the first dice roll, after that you never want to get $7$ again.  So in words, $E[R|win, S=4]$ says what is the expected number of rolls in a craps game given that you win the game and your initial sum is $4$. Apparently this is equal to $E[R|S=4]$. I'm sure you're busy but if you do post a response I will read it for sure!!

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry actually I think I'm good on this problem now. Fundamentally my problem was thinking $P(E \mid FG) = P(E \mid G)$ implied $F$ and $G$ were also independent. Because I was thinking the LHS and the RHS in the following $$\frac{P(EFG)}{P(FG)} = \frac{P(EG)}{P(G)} $$ $$\frac{P(EG)P(F)}{P(G)P(F)} = \frac{P(EG)}{P(G)} $$meant $P(FG) = P(F)P(G)$ but that is not necessarily correct. I forgot to use the fact that $P(EF \mid G) = P(E \mid G) P(F \mid G)$ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sides can be calculated directly.  Preliminary: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

$$P(R=r\mid\text{win},S=4)=\frac{P(R=r,\text{win}\mid S=4)}{P(\text{win}\mid S=4)}$$

Let $p_k=\operatorname{prob}(\text{roll} = k).$  Let $u=p_4+p_7$ and $v=1-u$, so termination at any roll has a probability $u$.  Therefore $P(R=r,\text{win} \mid S=4) = p_4v^{r-1}$, while $P(R=r\mid S=4)=uv^{r-1}$.  Forming the expectations, $E(\text{win stop}\mid S=4)=p_4\sum_{r=1}^\infty rv^{r-1} = \frac{p_4}{(1-v)^2} = \frac{p_4}{(p_4+p_7)^2}$ and $P(\text{win}\mid S=4)=\frac{p_4}{p_4+p_7}$. Therefore $E(\text{stop}\mid\text{win},S=4)=\frac{1}{p_4+p_7}$  Next $E(\text{stop}\mid S=4) = u \sum_{r=1}^\infty rv^{r-1} = \frac{u}{(1-v)^2)^2}=\frac{1}{p_4+p_7}$, so the two expectations are equal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hmmm it sounds like you're saying that $ E[R\mid\text{win},S=4] \neq E[R\mid S=4]$ and that the book is wrong? I'm still digesting how you get $P(R=r \mid win, S=4)$, it's like a geometric RV but $p_4 + v$ in your example does not equal $1$... I'm not saying you're wrong I just have to think about it =)

Comment: Win at $R=r$ means neither a 7 or a 4 came up in previous rolls and a 4 came up at $r$.  Similarly a stop at $R=r$ means neither a 7 or a 4 came up at previous rolls and a 7 or a 4 came up at $r$.  The calculation was just simply based on these observations.  There is no reason for $p_4+v=1$. $v$ is just the probability that it does not stop at a particular roll.

Comment: Hmmm that makes sense. So overall are you saying that $E[R\mid\text{win},S=4] \neq E[R\mid S=4]$

Comment: Yes (unless $p_7=0$, unlikely, unless dices are loaded).

Comment: Very interesting... I feel like the Lord Sheldon Ross is infallible. Well I've spotted a few typos in his book but this would be a big error in his reason. I will meditate on this...

Comment: I believe I was wrong and Ross is right.  I will correct my answer.

Comment: See my edits to this answer, for proper use of \mid and \text{} and \operatorname{}. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy  What are the rules (if any) about editing other people's posts - particularly without their permission and apparently with no recourse?

Comment: @HJ beginner My derivation has one major difference from your attempt.  I left $S=4$ as a condition throughout, moving only $win$, avoiding the question of independence of thee two conditions that troubled you.